# How to test update methods?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am new in unit testing and use JUnit in my Java (Spring Boot) app. I sometimes need to test update methods, but when I search on the web, there is not a proper example or suggestion. So, could you please clarify me how to test the following update method? I think this may require a different approach than testing void. I also thought that while testing first mocking the record and then update its field and then update. Finally retrieve the record again and compare the updated properties. But I think there may be more proper approach than this inexperienced one.

```
public PriceDTO update(UUID priceUuid, PriceRequest request) {
    Price price = priceRepository
                    .findByUuid(priceUuid)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(PRICE));

    mapRequestToEntity(request, price);
    Price updated = priceRepository.saveAndFlush(price);
    
    return new PriceDTO(updated);
}

private void mapRequestToEntity(PriceRequest request, Price entity) {
    entity.setPriceAmount(request.getPriceAmount());
    // set other props
}
```

Comment: Does anybody else have never write unit test for update methods?

Comment: Which piece of code is actually doing the update of the entity?

Comment: `priceRepository.saveAndFlush(price);` amigo.

Comment: That is updating the database, but I am talking about the `price` which should be updated according to `request`, right? Where is this done?

Comment: `mapRequestToEntity(request, price);`

Comment: Can you add the content of such a method to the question? In fact, can you include the whole class to the question? Thanks!

Comment: I added, but could not understand why you need it. Because I have an update method in my service and just try to write a unit test for it. I think all the part you need inside that method.

Comment: what exactly do you want to have tested? you do 3 things here:

- find existing (or throw)
- map dto to entity
- call save

Comment: call save amigo

Comment: I suggest you go back to reading what unit tests are and what they should do. There is no point trying to "unit test" an update method. If you want to test it properly then you write integration tests which use real data and a real database. Unit tests are about behaviour and all you have here is a basic CRUD method. Mocks are not going to help you here. A valuable unit test is one which has no knowledge about the code it tests and it tests behaviour as in what the code is supposed to do. There is no behavior in an update and that's not something you should try to cover with a "unit test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do something along the following lines:

```java
public class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private PriceRepository priceRepository;

    (...)

    @Test
    public void shouldUpdatePrice() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        UUID priceUuid = // build the Price UUID
        PriceRequest priceUpdateRequest = // build the Price update request
        Price originalPrice = // build the original Price  
        doReturn(originalPrice).when(this.priceRepository).findByUuid(isA(UUID.class));
        doAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg()).when(this.priceRepository).saveAndFlush(isA(Price.class));

        // Act
        PriceDTO updatedPrice = this.service.update(priceUuid, priceUpdateRequest);

        // Assert
        // here you need to assert that updatedPrice is as you expect according to originalPrice and priceUpdateRequest
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have no idea about how it works. Could you pls explain how `doReturn`, `doAnswer` and `PriceDTO updatedPrice = ...` lines work?

Comment: `doReturn` and `doAnswer` are basic Mockito methods that sets what the call define in the `when` clause is going to return when called in the real method. `PriceDTO updatedPrice = ...` line is just the call to the service `update()` method (`service` should be the attribute that has the instance of the class you are trying to test). If you are used to writing unit tests, all these things should be familiar to you.

Comment: I know most of them, but could not understand `doAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg()).when(this.priceRepository).saveAndFlush(isA(Price.class));
`. Could you clarify me about it?

Comment: This will basically return whatever is the first argument that is passed to the `priceRepository.saveAndFlush()` method, actually reproducing what a call to the real method would return in a success case.

Comment: so, let me get this right, you mock the call to the database, you mock the response and then you test that your mocked call returns the mocked result? what is the point of such a test? This isn't testing behavior, which is what a unit test should do and is not testing the real thing either. What have you achieved?

Comment: You are indeed testing that the `mapRequestToEntity()` method is in fact updating the `Price` object according to the `request`. Calls to the database are irrelevant while unit testing the code. Keep in mind that the returned `PriceDTO`is not mocked, but it is indeed created within the `mapRequestToEntity()` based on the `originalPrice` and `priceUpdateRequest` objects. Asserting the `PriceDTO` includes the data in `priceUpdateRequest` (which must be different from the `originalPrice`) actually tests the update logic (disregarding all persistence shenanigans).

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock the behavior of the class object `priceRepository`.
So you will have to write something like below to begin :

```
// priceRepository should be mocked in the test class
Mockito.when(priceRepository.findByUuid(any(UUID.class))).thenReturn(new Price());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what about the rest? Could you please post an example test method?

Comment: without seeing the actual implementation, it would be hard to comment.  For void methods, you need to use the `doNothing()` method to mock the behavior.

Comment: No, I did not mean that. I just mean if I should call the `findByUuid` method of the service and then fill the properties of the returned entity. Could you include these parts in your example?

Comment: Amigo? Any reply pls?

Answer (score 1):

So if your only intention is to verify if you called save, then something like this is probably what you are looking for:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private PriceRepository priceRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void update() throws Exception {
        // Given
        Price price = new Price();
        price.setUid(UUID.randomUUID());
        price.setPriceAmount(100);

        when(priceRepository.findByUid(price.getUid()))
            .thenReturn(price);

        ArgumentCaptor<Price> priceArgument =                      
            ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Price.class);

        when(incidentRepository.saveAndFlush(priceArgument.capture()))
            .thenAnswer(iom -> iom.getArgument(0));


        // When
        PriceRequest priceRequest = new PriceRequest();
        priceRequest.setPriceAmount(123);

        PriceDTO updatedPrice = this.service.update(price.getUid(), priceUpdateRequest);

        // Then
        assertThat(priceArgument.getValue().getPriceAmount())
            .isEqualTo(123);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer, but as far as I know and you can see on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70590208/proper-usage-of-mockito-argumentcaptor-in-java/70593051?noredirect=1#comment124811362_70593051) page, there is no need to use `ArgumentCaptor` as the Update method returns DTO (I can already reach the returned value). So, any idea?

Comment: the argument captoring makes perfectly sense as it is the actual value you are passing to the save method. every other value, e.g. the one that is returned is not the same that you passed to the save method